# mapping for keys having same value java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, dictionary

For instance, 
the map **{key : value}** like this

`A : 1`

`B : 2`

`C : 3`

`D : 3`

How can I separate the keys into lists like [A,B,C],[A,B,D] based on the values in map?
Because the set for map values is [1,2,3], since keys for 3 are C and D, then there will be two mapping lists.

```
ArrayList<Object> item1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
ArrayList<Object> repeated = new ArrayList<Object>();
Set<Object> getKeys = map.keySet();
Collection<Object> getValues = map.values();
ArrayList<Object> keyArray = new ArrayList<Object>(getKeys);
ArrayList<Object> valueArray = new ArrayList<Object>(getValues);    


for (int i=0 ; i < keyArray.size(); i++){
    int y = Collections.frequency(valueArray, valueArray.get(i));
    if (y == 1){
        item1.add(valueArray.get(i));
    }else{
        repeated.add(valueArray.get(i));
    }
}

ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> possibleKeyCombination = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
for (Object r : repeated){
    ArrayList<Object> table = new ArrayList<List<Object>>(item1);
    table.add(r);
    possibleKeyCombination.add(table);
}
```

Now, I can solve this particular question. However, when the mapping turns complex, my code would not work. For example,

`A : 1,3`

`B : 2`

`C : 3`

`D : 3`

Comment: What would you get from {A:1, B:1, C:1, D:1, E:2, F:2, G:3, H:3}?

Comment: @kk988 I don't get it, how is it unique?

Comment: @immibis the total unique list = 4*2*2 [AEG][AFG][AEH][AFH]....

Comment: I am not sure that I got it, but I think you need a new Map with the values of the first as keys and the keys of the first as values (list)...

Comment: There is no built-in way to do this. You need to write it yourself (or convince someone to do it for you).

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, there is no predefined method to do, what you want. You could get all values by calling map.values() and then create manually a List of all Keys corresponding to a value. All what is left afterwards is calculating all possible combination.